# How to reduce FontAwesome bundle size?

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

During my latest attempt to make my page load faster, I noticed that FortAwesome makes up 1.08MB during my page load:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The module you're looking at is my `SharedModule` which adds icons etc in the constructor of the module:

```
// ..
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {faCoffee, fas} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {faAndroid, faAppStoreIos, faFacebook, faInstagram, faSlack} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import {faLinkedin} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faLinkedin';
// ..
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ExportModules
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModules,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    ExportModules
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {

  constructor() {
    library.add(faCoffee);
    library.add(fas, faInstagram);
    library.add(fas, faFacebook);
    library.add(fas, faLinkedin);
    library.add(fas, faSlack);
    library.add(fas, faAndroid);
    library.add(fas, faAppStoreIos);
  }

}
```

Since all I am loading here are a few SVGs I would like to exlude the rest if possible.

Is there a way to reduce FortAwesomes bundle size?

Comment: As an option: you may be able to serve a modified copy of FontAwesome via html <head> tag without build with your project.

Answer (score 16):

Your problem is `fas` you're including all solid icons, and after you included them multiple times in the library. you need to delete `fas`.

the way you call linkendin is the most optimized way to call the icons, apply this for all the icons. Your code with the proposed changes:

```js
// ..
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCoffee';
import { faAndroid } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faAndroid';
import { faAppStoreIos } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faAppStoreIos';
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faFacebook';
import { faInstagram } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faInstagram';
import { faSlack } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faSlack';
import { faLinkedin } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faLinkedin';
// ..
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ExportModules
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModules,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    ExportModules
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {

  constructor() {
    library.add(
      faCoffee,
      faInstagram,
      faFacebook,
      faLinkedin,
      faSlack,
      faAndroid,
      faAppStoreIos
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I found no difference when loading icons via direct path to the component vs loading multiple icons in a single `import` statement.

Comment: The result size depends on the configuration you have to build the package. Multiple imports is a safe way to be sure the build just includes the right icons and not all.

Comment: Turns out this has nothing to do with it. See my new answer below with a reference to the documentation for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the important bit from [the official documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react#using-icons)

There are two ways to include icons. Individually, or globally. The global method means you will not have an optimized bundle.

> You may be including files that won't be used and could impact
> performance.

Including icons individually, *read:* in each and every file rather than just using `FontAwesomeIcon` alone, supports optimized bundles.